# Appropriate Exception to raise during API access failure

Tags: python, web-services

When coding a class that provides abstraction over one or more HTTP APIs that it transparently consumes, what is the appropriate Exception to raise when the service request ends up in a `HTTP 404` or similar?

The class is intended as a composite object for consumers who have a high-level overview of what services are being consumed but would appreciate a specific exception for failures at the API access level. Of course, one could always write and raise a Custom Exception Object:

```
class WebServiceUnresponsive(Exception):
    pass
```

But going through, [Standard Python Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html), I am not sure if I am  overlooking a suitable candidate. What is the best practice if not this?

Comment: Why not use an HTTP library, like [requests.exceptions](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/exceptions/), specifically [raise_for_status()](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes)?

Comment: I see the most of the requests exceptions are inheriting `IOError` or `ValueError` which kind of answers this question in another way, as in how the `requests` people thought of it. Anyway, great suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Use `requests`:

[requests.exceptions](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/exceptions/) contains a multitude of built-in HTTP exceptions, and includes a specific [response.raise_for_status()](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes), which does all the heavy lifting for you (example from the link):

```
>>> bad_r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/status/404')
>>> bad_r.status_code
404

>>> bad_r.raise_for_status()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests/models.py", line 832, in raise_for_status
    raise http_error
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error
```

If you aren't using requests directly, you can `from requests import exceptions` and then throw your own.

```
if exception_encountered(req):
    raise exceptions.HTTPError("Got a 404 yo... server says there's nothing there :(")
```